# set cache headers only when something changed in the website (php, htaccess)

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, .htaccess, caching

I'm running wordpress. Added this code in .htaccess file so that users will see latest version of website and not the cached one.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Header set Cache-Control "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
    Header set Pragma "no-cache"
    Header set Expires 0
</IfModule>
```

But now it loads very slowly and the reason is clear. Cause every time when am refreshing, it loads new files again. I was wondering is there any other way to detect when something had been changed, only then add these headers or clear cache in other way. Don't want to use any plugin. Want to fix it via some php or javascript code. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I'm using now cookies in my website. But how can I connect cookies with this ? @Rahul Dambare

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set expires headers for different file extensions like so:

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
  ExpiresActive on

  # Your document html
  ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 0 seconds"

  # Media: images, video, audio
  ExpiresByType audio/ogg "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType video/mp4 "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType video/ogg "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType video/webm "access plus 1 month"

  # CSS and JavaScript
  ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 year"
  ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 year"
</IfModule>
```

For specific files that you know will be changed on a more regular basis, you can add an extension such as `?=[timestamp]` to the URL, so that the browser recognises it as a new version.

For example, you could change the `.js` file to `main.js?version=2` when you want the viewer to see a new version.

Alternatively you can change the extension to `main.js?ts=<?php echo date() ?>` for the file to be reloaded on every visit, because the timestamp will be different each time.

---

**Edit** Another solution would be to use the last-edited time of the file (using `filemtime()`) to append as a parameter, like so:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='main.js?fmt=<?= filemtime("main.js") ?>'>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url'); echo '?ver=' . filemtime( get_stylesheet_directory() . '/style.css'); ?>" type="text/css" media="all" />
```

This would mean that the first load after a change in the file's data would force a refresh.

Comment: what do you think about using FilesMatch directive in .htaccess files ?

Comment: Not sure if it's any easier than the above solution. You'd have to specify regexes, filenames or extensions for `FilesMatch` or `Files` while here you only need extensions and it's easy to add/edit new files on your server without changing `.htaccess`.

Comment: so via your code I can be 100% sure that when something new is added or changed in css or js files, users will always see newer version of it and they wouldn't need to do Ctrl+F5 to clear cache ?

Comment: Only if (1) the file is past its expiration or (2) if the file has not been cached before. To force a refresh *for* the user, you can rename a file (such as by adding a variable parameter to the end, like `?t=1234`)

Comment: and every time when I change css or javascript file, I need to change that parameter value(for example ?t=1254) ? @Ben Pearl Kahan

Comment: @aidaghazaryan you can either change it like a version (e.g. just leave it as `?v=1` until you want to force a cache change, then change it to `?v=2`) or, for files you want to force a cache refresh on *every* load, use a variable value, like the timestamp (e.g. `?t=<?php echo date() ?>`)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102892/discussion-between-aidaghazaryan-and-ben-pearl-kahan).